# EditText does not receive focus

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout with Textview and several EditText  finally a LinearLayout with two EditText. When I run the application and I press the Next key keyboard focus works ok, from one EditText to another. However, when the focus is on the first EditText of the LinearLayout the focus does not move to another EditText.

Help please

Here's my layout file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_nombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_nombre" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edi_nombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_nombre" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_apellido"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_apellido"
        android:layout_below="@id/edi_nombre" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edi_apellido"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_apellido" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_username"
        android:layout_below="@id/edi_apellido" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edi_username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_username" />    

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_email"
        android:layout_below="@id/edi_username" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edi_email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_email" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyo_pwd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edi_email"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_pwd"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lbl_pwd"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_repwd"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lbl_repwd"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyo_edipwd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lyo_pwd"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edi_pwd"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edi_repwd"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>         
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_registrar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_registrar"
        android:layout_below="@id/lyo_edipwd" />        
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any solution without using java code?

Comment: Is this running on an emulator or real device ?

Comment: In both emulator and disposiivo

Answer (score 0):

try focusing programmatically, like this:

-copy this method to your activity:

```
public void setEditTextFocus(boolean isFocused){
    yourEditText.setCursorVisible(isFocused);
    yourEditText.setFocusable(isFocused);
    yourEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(isFocused);
    if (isFocused){
        yourEditText.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

-and in your onCreate:

```
setEditTextFocus(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. I had tried this but wanted to understand why it fails.